# RegEx for removing words that contain a character *not* in a specified set

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string, lets say something like:

```
' abc a b c ab ac ae '
```

I've got a set of characters that I like, lets say something like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I'm trying to remove any words that contain a character that is *not* in the set. I'm using JS, but a regex-is-a-regex, so any help, language-agnostic, would be oodles of help.

I tried something like this, but it didn't do the voodoo I was hoping for:

```
var str = ' abc a b c ab ac ae ';
var regex = new RegExp(' [a|b|c].[^a|b|c]+[a|b|c]. ', 'gi');
console.log(str.replace(regex, ' '));
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you mention what you would like capture from `var str` I can modify my answer to accomodate. Currently I am assuming you only want to capture `ae`

Answer (score 4):

The `^` is the not character so `[^abc]` says that the character can not be a,b or c. Try this regex `[abc][^abc]+` that should match ae

Edit: Modified regex to ignore whitespace
`[a-c][^a-c\s]+`

Comment: my concern with your modified regex is that it's actually a set of characters, not a range. any thoughts?

Comment: `[abc][^abc\s]+` is equivalent and you can use that. The range is just for convenience but is not necessary when there is only 3 characters since it takes 3 characters to make a range.

Comment: with str = ' abc a b c ab ac Ae ai Xa Xxi xab aa bca ';, and the regexp new RegExp(' [abc][^abc\s]+ ', 'gi');, it doesn't seem to be matching everything?

Comment: make sure you escape the \s as \\s and get rid of the extra space around the regex unless you want to capture spaces. `'[abc][^abc\\s]+'` or `' [abc][^abc]+ '` to capture spaces.

Comment: Also in that string please let me know what you want captured. currently the regex will only capture values that start with a,b or c and then have one or more character not containing a,b,c or space

Comment: cleaned it up a bit. here's what im running:
var str = ' abc a b c ab ac Ae ai Xa Xxi xab aa bca ';
console.log(str.replace(/\s[abc]*[^abc\s]+[abc]* /g, ' '));

response is: abc a b c ab ac ai Xxi aa bca 
thoughts?

Comment: Ok that regex is looking for something starts with any whitespace character, then 0 or 1 a,b or c characters then 1 or more characters that are not a,b,c or whitespace then 0 or more a,b or c characters followed by a space. Please explain what you are expecting to be returned or more specifically what exactly should your regex be checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
\s[abc]*[^abc\s]+[abc]*\s
```

This will include the space either side, which from your code is what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to allow for `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

To me `[^abc]` is a class that represents %99 of everything (what you don't want), when in reality thats too broad of a brush to be the only positive requirement. It needs a counter weight that shaves this down a little more. That shaving can't be done very well in a negative sence like a character class. Its already been modified to include \s.

It might be better to look for words with nothing but these things in it, then exclude them from a match.

`/(?!\b[abc]+\b)\b\w+\b/`

expanded:

```
/     # Rx delim
  (?! \b[abc]+\b )             # Not \b [abc]+ \b in front of us
  \b \w+ \b                    # Match this word, it needs to go
/x    # Rx delim, Xpanded modifier but not in JavaScript
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support `/x`, or free-spacing mode.  And I don't see the point of the nested lookahead, or replacing the character class with a group.  Surely `(?!\b[abc]+\b)` will work just as well, won't it?